# Strip Parameter from URL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-replace

I have a table that has URLs captured that have a number of parameters. The URLs look like this: http://www.xxxx.com/?p=XXX&impfield1=QQQ&impfield2=YYY&testfield=ZZZ

I'm trying to write a query that will strip out specific parameters, i.e., impfield1.

How can I do this in MySQL? I've tried the preg_replace plugins but I was unable to get them installed on my windows MySQL server (installed using the WAMP bundle).

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a PHP script to do this, but I'm getting memory errors when using PDO and fputcsv. Is there a trick to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better off doing this through PHP or some kind of scripting language that has DB access. You could write a simple function to string search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a script to do this with your favorite programming language.  Python would be good at it.

1. Install python mysql driver
2. Write python script to select records, process them, run updates
3. Run it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a go-to python mysql plugin? I haven't done much with Python but this looks like a great way to get started.